# UNITY - How to perform a different action for Long click and a single click/double click?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, mouseevent, collision, onmousedown

so I am making a 2D character controller where if the mouse is held down(Long click) a player can set a direction of where he wants to fire a projectile, and when the projectile is fired and collided with an object the player can click once(or double click if it's better) to swap the character's position to the projectile's position. I'm trying to do it using Input.onMouseButton and Input.onMouseButtonDown but I can't really figure out. Thank you for everyone that'll help me!

Comment: On onMouseButtonDown, you will set a flag `boolean mousePressed = true; float mousePressDuration = 0`, and then in your update `if mousePressed { mousePressDuration += time.deltaTime; }`Just dont forget that onMouseButtonUp you must set mousePressed back to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a long click, you just need to measure the amount to time passed since the first click. Here is an example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class LongClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float ClickDuration = 2;
    public UnityEvent OnLongClick;

    bool clicking = false;
    float totalDownTime = 0;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Detect the first click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            totalDownTime = 0;
            clicking = true;
        }

        // If a first click detected, and still clicking,
        // measure the total click time, and fire an event
        // if we exceed the duration specified
        if (clicking && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            totalDownTime += Time.deltaTime;

            if (totalDownTime >= ClickDuration)
            {
                Debug.Log("Long click");
                clicking = false;
                OnLongClick.Invoke();
            }
        }

        // If a first click detected, and we release before the
        // duraction, do nothing, just cancel the click
        if (clicking && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            clicking = false;
        }
    }
}
```

For a double click, you just need to check whether a second click occurs within a specified (short) interval:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class DoubleClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float DoubleClickInterval = 0.5f;
    public UnityEvent OnDoubleClick;

    float secondClickTimeout = -1;

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (secondClickTimeout < 0)
            {
                // This is the first click, calculate the timeout
                secondClickTimeout = Time.time + DoubleClickInterval;
            }
            else
            {
                // This is the second click, is it within the interval 
                if (Time.time < secondClickTimeout)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Double click!");

                    // Invoke the event
                    OnDoubleClick.Invoke();

                    // Reset the timeout
                    secondClickTimeout = -1;
                }
            }

        }

        // If we wait too long for a second click, just cancel the double click
        if (secondClickTimeout > 0 && Time.time >= secondClickTimeout)
        {
            secondClickTimeout = -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the docs and forums, you will need to check using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` and the time passed since the first press, like [so](https://forum.unity.com/threads/differencing-short-mouse-click-from-long-mouse-click.77819/).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from getting the GetMouseButtonDown(int) with the button, you want to track remember to check in which phase it's the button.

[TouchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html)